# Passing procs and methods

Tags: ruby, proc

I came across this code:

```
squareIt = Proc.new do |x|
  x * x
end

doubleIt = Proc.new do |x|
  x + x
end

def compose proc1, proc2
  Proc.new do |x|
    proc2.call(proc1.call(x))
  end
end

doubleThenSquare = compose(doubleIt, squareIt)
squareThenDouble = compose(squareIt, doubleIt)

doubleThenSquare.call(5)
squareThenDouble.call(5)
```

`doubleThenSquare` is called with `5`. `doubleThenSquare` is equal to the return value of `compose`, which has its two parameters `doubleIt` and `squareIt` passed.

I don't see how `5` is passed all its way into the different procs `Proc.new do |x|`. How does it know what `x` is in each case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's step through it.

```
doubleIt = Proc.new do |x|
  x + x
end
  #=> #<Proc:0x00000002326e08@(irb):1429>

squareIt = Proc.new do |x|
  x * x
end
  #=> #<Proc:0x00000002928bf8@(irb):1433>

proc1 = doubleIt
proc2 = squareIt
```

`compose` returns the proc `proc3`.

```
proc3 = Proc.new do |x|
    proc2.call(proc1.call(x))
end
  #=> #<Proc:0x000000028e7608@(irb):1445>
```

`proc3.call(x)` is executed in the same way as

```
proc3_method(x)
```

where

```
def proc3_method(x)
  y = proc1.call(x)
  proc2.call(y)
end
```

When `x = 5`,

```
y = proc1.call(5)
  #=> 10
proc2.call(10)
  #=> 100
```

`proc3_method(5)` therefore returns `100`, as does `proc3.call(5)`.

Comment: This step through makes sense, the part thats difficult for me is how the (5) is making it's way to "proc3" in the original code. I know we "call" `doubleThenSquare` but `doubleThenSquare` itself isn't a proc function, it calls a method with a proc function in it (lets call that proc3). So thats where my confusion lies. Since we are actually calling something that is storing the return value of a method WITH a proc function in it...but not an actual proc function itself.

Comment: `doubleThenSquare` is a variable that is assigned the proc returned by `compose(doubleIt, squareIt)`. That proc has a variable, but that variable is not assigned a value (e.g. `5`) until `doubleThenSquare` is called.

Comment: Ah so it's able to pass it because a proc is being returned by `compose`...man that's confusing, since I assumed calling a proc it would need a variable directly (whatever you are calling)

Comment: Yes, you've got it. There's an analogous situation with methods. Suppose `def m(x) 2*x end`. We could then write `method(:m).call(3) #=> 6` or `public_send(:m, 3) #=> 6`. `method(:m)` converts a method name (`:m`) to a method object. Being an object, it can be passed around like a proc, and like a proc, is invoked with `call` (but with [Method#call](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Method.html#method-i-call), not [Proc#call](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Proc.html#method-i-call)).

Comment: I guess it's not too crazy hopefully for that to be slighty confusing to me I hope haha (I just started learning ruby)